# Numeric Data Type - Storage

Tags: sql, sql-server

According to [Microsoft Site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms187746(v=sql.110).aspx)  a data with type Numeric(10,2) - 10 means precision should have 9 bytes.

But when I'm doing this:

```
DECLARE @var as numeric(10,0) = 2147483649

SELECT @var, DATALENGTH(@var)
```

DATALENGTH(@var) is returning 5 bytes instead of 10. Can someone explain me why?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/184325/3690

Answer (score 0):

The documentation specifies:

> Maximum storage sizes vary, based on the precision.

The storage is not constant for a given precision.  The actual storage depends on the value.

As a note, this has nothing to do with integerness.  The following also returns 5:

```
declare @var numberic(11, 1) = 214483649.8
```

In actual fact, SQL Server seems to use the amount of storage needed for the *value*, not for the *maximum value* of the type.  You can readily see this by changing the "10" to "20" and noting that the data length does not change.

EDIT:

You can see the dependence on the value if you run:

```
declare @a numeric(20, 1) = '123.1';
declare @b numeric(20, 1) = '1234567890123456789.0';
select datalength(@a), datalength(@b);
```

The two lengths are not the same.

Comment: I still don't get it. Precision is set to '11' and storage should be 9.

Comment: @Jake . . . The *maximum* storage is 9 bytes.  The *actual* storage depends on the value being stored.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting that storage depends on actual value.  But for 
           numeric(10,0) = 1234567891 actual precision is 10 and storage is still 5.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what exactly do you mean - that the amount of storage for numeric is variable?  That a numeric (10,2) can take a variable number of bytes depending on the actual value? numeric is a fixed size data type, so in the row it is always stored in the fixed length portion of the data, before the variable length fields.

Comment: @AshleyPillay . . . See my edit.  You are wrong.  `numeric`s/`decimal`s are not fixed length.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer, by @GordonLinoff is wrong, or at least misleading.
`Numeric` is not stored with a variable number of bytes, but with a fixed size for a specific precision.

Trying this on SQL Server 2017 gave the same results you got.

The documentation you linked to originally, for `numeric`, is correct about how many bytes it takes to store a numeric of varying precisions.

This storage requirement is based only on the precision of the `numeric` column. In other words, that's how many bytes of storage are used. It is not a maximum that depends on the value in that row.
All rows use the same number of bytes for that column.

The key to this variation is the documentation for `DATALENGTH` says this function

> [Returns the number of bytes used to represent any expression.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql)

It appears that `DATALENGTH` goes not mean 'represent' as in 'represent' on disk, but rather 'represent' in memory.
The other documenation regarding `numeric` is talking about the on-disk storage of `numeric`.

This is probably because `DATALENGTH` is intended primarily for var* types or the other BLOB types.

So although a `numeric(20,1)` requires 13 bytes of storage, depending on the value, SQL Server can represent it in a smaller number of bytes when in memory, which is when `DATALENGTH` evaluates it.

As I pointed out in my other comment, although `numeric` has different sizes, it a fixed size data type, because for a specific column in a specific table, every values takes up the same amount of storage.

Roughly, a SQL Server row has 4 parts:

1. 4 byte header
2. Fixed size data
3. Offsets into variable size data
4. Variable size data

Numerics & other fixed size types are stored in 2, `var*` are stored in 4, with lengths in 3.

This script displays the metadata for a table with some fixed & variable columns.

```
declare @a numeric(20, 1) = '123.1';
declare @b numeric(20, 1) = '1234567890123456789.0';
select datalength(@a) union select datalength(@b);

create table #numeric(num1 numeric(20,1), text1 varchar(10), char2 char(6));
insert into #numeric(num1, text1, char2) values ('123.1', 'hello', 'first'), ('1234567890123456789.0', 'there', '2nd');

select datalength(num1) from #numeric;

select
    t.name as table_name,
    c.name as column_name,
    pc.partition_column_id,
    pc.max_inrow_length,
    pc.max_length,
    pc.precision,
    pc.scale,
    pc.collation_name,
    pc.leaf_offset
from tempdb.sys.tables as t
join tempdb.sys.partitions as p
    on(t.object_id=p.object_id)
join tempdb.sys.system_internals_partition_columns as pc
    on(pc.partition_id=p.partition_id)
join tempdb.sys.columns as c
    on((c.object_id=p.object_id)and(c.column_id=pc.partition_column_id))
where (t.object_id=object_id('tempdb..#numeric'));

drop table #numeric;
```

Notice the `leaf_offset` column. This indicates the starting position of the value in the raw binary data.
The first column starts immediately after the 4 byte header.
The second fixed column starts 13 bytes later, as per the SQL documentation.
The `varchar` column has an offset of -1, indicating it is a variable length column & it's position in the byte array isn't fixed.
In this case it could be fixed since there's only 1 var column, but an `alter table` statement could add another column & shift things.

If you want to research further, the best source is a book called SQL Server Internals, by Kalen Delaney. She was part of the team that wrote SQL Server.

Comment: If you want to verify this another way, you can use `sys.fn_PhysLocCracker(%%physloc%%)` to get the page, then use DBCC PAGE to output the binary data.